# watchOS 7 beta networking gives SSL error

Tags: ios, networking, alamofire, watchos, watchos-7

I have a watch app that is working OK with watchOS 6. It uses AlamoFire 5 for networking.

Testing it with watchOS 7, it gives this error "Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made." if I disable Certificate Pinning (PinnedCertificatesTrustEvaluator).

If I enable it, the error is "Code=-67820 "Certificate 2 “Trusted Root CA SHA256 G2” has errors: Certificate is revoked;".

The same certificate I use on the app on watchOS 6 and it was generated with the openssl command (openssl s_client -connect <SITE_URL>:443 </dev/null | openssl x509 -outform DER -out cert.der).

I have nothing related to networking configured in a .plist.

Someone knows what's changed in watchOS 7 or need to be done in Alamofire 5 ?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does this project work correctly on watchOS 6?

Comment: Yes. Same project working flawlessly.

Comment: Then I would suggest this is a watchOS 7 bug that you should report to Apple. It appears something has changed in regards to certificate validation.